# MNIST GAN generator loss increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-models, mnist

I'm trying to train a simple vanilla GAN on MNIST with Tensorflow. I used [this github page](https://github.com/znxlwm/tensorflow-MNIST-GAN-DCGAN/blob/master/tensorflow_MNIST_GAN.py) as a reference and in my process to try and get my GAN to work I've made my code more and more similar to this reference to the point where it's almost an exact copy.

My issue is that while training, it seems to immediately converge to a situation where the discriminator loss is very low and the generator's is high, producing horrible output.

I've messed around with training the discriminator/generator more than the other one, and right now I'm actually only feeding the discriminator 1 MNIST digit to see if it can learn just that (it can't). I even downloaded my reference and ran it on my computer, and in just a few epochs it produced something number looking. I'm totally stumped as to what's going on here as MNIST should be a fairly easy to solve problem.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 
import mnist
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
import math

#NOTE: heavily references this repo: https://github.com/znxlwm/tensorflow-MNIST-GAN-DCGAN/blob/master/tensorflow_MNIST_GAN.py 


# Check for GPU availability
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")

# Get data from MNIST
# NOTE: I did not write the code to retrieve the data, code taken from:
# https://github.com/hsjeong5/MNIST-for-Numpy
imgTrain, lblTrain, imgTest, lblTest = mnist.load()

#Hyperparameters
batchSize = 100
learningRate = 0.0002
dropoutRate = 0.3

# Dimensions of noise
zDim = 100
# Dimensions of MNIST
imageDim = 784

# Dimensions of hidden layers (backwards for descriminator)
hdim0 = 256
hdim1 = 512
hdim2 = 1024

# Generates the images
def generator(z):

    # First layer
    w0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([zDim, hdim0], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_w0")
    b0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim0], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_b0")
    l0 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(z,w0) + b0)

    # Second layer
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim0, hdim1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_w1")
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_b1")
    l1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l0,w1) + b1)

    # Third layer
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim1, hdim2], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_w2")
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim2], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_b2")
    l2 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l1,w2) + b2)

    # Output
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim2, imageDim], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_w3")
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([imageDim], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="g_b3")
    output = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(l2,w3) + b3)

    return output

# Determines whether an image is real or fake
def discriminator(x):
    # First layer
    w0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([imageDim, hdim2], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_w0")
    b0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim2], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_b0")
    l0 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(x,w0) + b0)

    # Second layer
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim2, hdim1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_w1")
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_b1")
    l1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l0,w1) + b1)

    # Third layer
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim1, hdim0], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_w2")
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim0], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_b2")
    l2 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l1,w2) + b2)

    # Output
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hdim0, 1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_w3")
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1], mean=0, stddev=0.02), name="d_b3")
    output = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(l2,w3) + b3)

    return output


with tf.variable_scope("G"):
    # Noise input for generator
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, zDim])
    # G(z): the generated image based off of z (noise)
    Gz = generator(z)


with tf.variable_scope("D") as scope:
    # Image input for discriminator
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, imageDim])
    # D(x): the discriminator's confidence in the real images
    Dx = discriminator(x)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    # D(G(z)): the discriminator's confidence in the fake images
    Dgz = discriminator(Gz)

# Fixes some issues
epsilon = 1e-2

# Discriminator loss
dLoss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(Dx+epsilon) - tf.log(1-Dgz+epsilon))
# Generator loss
gLoss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(Dgz+epsilon))

# Gets weights and biases of each network
TVars = tf.trainable_variables()
dVars = [var for var in TVars if "d_" in var.name]
gVars = [var for var in TVars if "g_" in var.name]

# Optimizer for discriminator
dOptimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learningRate).minimize(dLoss, var_list=dVars)
# Optimizer for generator
gOptimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learningRate).minimize(gLoss, var_list = gVars)


# Initialize session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Saves variable information
saver = tf.train.Saver()
# Path to save information to
savingPath = "data/MNISTGAN.ckpt"

# If the path exists restore the variables of the network
if(len(os.listdir("data"))>0):
    print("Restoring variables...")
    saver.restore(sess, savingPath)
# If not, initialize the variables as new
else:
    print("Initializing variables...")
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

def prepareInputVector(vector):
    # Divides by 255 to squash it
    returnVector = np.divide(vector, 255)
    returnVector = np.multiply(np.add(returnVector, -0.5),2)
    # Shapes it correctly and returns it
    returnVector.shape = (1,imageDim)
    return returnVector


def prepareBatch(size):
    returnArray = np.zeros((size,imageDim))
    for i in range(size):
        returnArray[i] = prepareInputVector(imgTrain[random.randint(0, 59999)])

    return returnArray


def convertArray(array):
    return np.reshape(np.multiply(np.divide(np.add(array,1),2), 255), (28,28))

def generateRandomImage(name):

    noise = np.random.normal(0,1, (1, zDim))
    generatedArray = sess.run(Gz, feed_dict={z: noise})
    imgArray = convertArray(generatedArray)
    generatedImg = Image.fromarray(imgArray).convert('RGB').resize((168,168), Image.LANCZOS)
    generatedImg.save("generated/"+name+".png")



epochs = 1000000
logInterval = 1
# How many epochs the discriminator trains for every 1 generator epoch
epochInterval = 1

for i in range(epochs):

    # Stores loss values 
    dLosses = []
    gLosses = []


    for j in range(60000//batchSize):

        noise = np.random.normal(0,1, (batchSize, zDim))
        imgBatch = prepareBatch(batchSize)
        currentDLoss, p,= sess.run([dLoss, dOptimizer], feed_dict={z:noise, x:imgBatch})
        dLosses.append(currentDLoss)

        # Generate new batch of noise
        noise = np.random.normal(0,1, (batchSize, zDim))

        # Optimises generator
        currentGLoss, b = sess.run([gLoss, gOptimizer], feed_dict={z:noise})
        # Records loss
        gLosses.append(currentGLoss)

    if(i%logInterval == 0):
        print("Epoch:" + str(i) + "\n")
        print("Generator loss:\n")
        print(np.mean(gLosses))
        print("\n")
        print("Discriminator loss: \n")
        print(str(np.mean(dLosses)))
        print("\n")

        savePath = saver.save(sess, savingPath)
        generateRandomImage(str(i))


sess.close()
```

Here are some of the results I got:

[image: All of the results were identical to this image]

I don't have graphs of the loss, but the generator loss shoots up to about 4.6 after 1-2 epochs, and the discriminator loss sits at around -0.02.

Comment: Are you feeding all the dataset (Mnist data 0 to 9) in a single train?

Comment: Right now the only thing that I'm feeding it is a single image of a zero 100 times per batch